# Why do jet planes with multiple engines have separate throttle levers for each engine?

Tags: jet-engine, flight-controls, multi-engine, throttle

What are the reasons to not just use one throttle lever for all engines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All multi-engine airplanes, whether jet or prop driven have separate throttle controls for each engine. There are good reasons for this:

- If there is a problem with one engine you can separately control it for troubleshooting purposes
- If one engine isn't developing the right amount of power you can independently increase the other engine(s) to compensate
- If you have a control failure of some kind you can use differential thrust to steer the airplane, this has been done more than once, the example that comes immediately to mind is [United 232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_232)

Comment: Most modern engines use digital electronic FADEC control. It would be very easy to have one thrust lever and still accommodate separate control for all the reasons given above. I have to assume the really reason might be something else. ( like tradition)

Comment: Differential thrust is also very helpful in taxi, not just in the event of control failure. I often use differential thrust as my primary directional control in taxi.

Comment: @Mike Sowsun: Turn the question around, though, and ask whether there are any good reasons to have a single throttle control.  I can't think of any, but then I'm used to just having one engine :-)

Comment: To extend the question considering this answer and comments: are there devices that can selectively 'gang' all thrust levers, to avoid unintended differential settings? Like when a pilot wants to move all to TOGA but lets one slip?

Comment: There _are_ military twin-engine jets with a single 'throttle'. [Rafale](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/31953/13666), for example.

Comment: @RobVermeulen, the levers are always made such that you can grab them all at once and move them together. In many aircraft the significant settings (TO/GA, MCT, FLEX, CLB and IDLE) also have detents to assist in precise positioning of the levers.